# How do I install a LaTeX .sty file on OSX?

Tags: macos, latex

I have a LaTeX project set up:

```
tex/
  - documents/
      - some_file.tex
  - support/
      - todonotes.sty
```

where `some_file.tex` uses `todonotes`:

```
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,textwidth=0.9\marginparwidth]{todonotes}
```

But I get "LaTeX Error: File `todonotes.sty' not found" when I try to build the PDF in TextMate. How do I tell LaTex or TextMate about my .sty file?

**Later**

To be specific, I'm using `tetex` from MacPorts, though given the answers so far, I might try another distribution.

Comment: sorry I didn't see you were using tetex. Its probably pretty old... check out MacTeX, its quite nice, and the package manager is pretty good.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Mac OS X (Snow Leopard 10.6.7) put your `.sty` file in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2010basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/
```

Then, run `texhash` command. Don't forget to stay as a root user (like `sudo -s` )

Comment: how do I see /usr/local... I could not find it

Comment: Or type Cmd-Shift-G in Finder to open the "Go to path" menu

Comment: @Aku: You may not actually have that particular directory. For example, mine is "/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/". Try looking through those folders on the command line (e.g. using the Terminal app as Mikey suggested), but be prepared for the exact folder to not match exactly -- especially the directory underneath "/usr/local/texlive/".

Comment: Correct directory for me was `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/`.

Answer (score 41):

Or you can just put the style file in the same directory as your document instead of in "support." now... if you're on OS X, you should probably be using texlive 2008. If you are using texlive 2008, pop open a terminal and type:

```
sudo tlmgr install todonotes
```

replace "todonotes" with the package name you want to install.

Comment: And the nicest way to install TeXLive 2008 on Mac OS X is MacTeX: https://www.tug.org/mactex/  MacTeX includes the TeX Live Utility, which is a native Mac OS X graphical interface for tlmgr.

Comment: or if you have perl/tk installed, in the terminal type: sudo tlmgr --gui

Answer (score 12):

You can put style files in `~/texmf/tex/` and standard LaTeX distributions should find them. If you prefer to install them system-wide, you can put them in the corresponding `texmf/tex` folder within your LaTeX installation (the location of this installation on OS X varies depending on which LaTeX distribution you used).

You can use `tlmgr conf` at the command line to list all of the distribution configuration information. The `TEXMFHOME` variable gives the path to your texmf tree.

Comment: `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/` is the place to put it in MacTeX.

Comment: Thanks, Will. The inconsistency in texmf, especially  on the Mac, is a bummer. The ~/texmf/... works for Unix-y installations (like from Fink or MacPorts), so thanks for adding info about MacTeX.

Comment: Yes, `tlmgr conf`. I'll edit the answer to include that info.

Comment: Just by way of making this more up to date. As of at least MacTex 2011 ~/texmf will work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

As said before just put the custom `.sty` into `~/texmf/tex` or in `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/` but don’t forget to run `mktexlsr` or `texhash` to update the local package database of LaTeX. Otherwise LaTeX won’t find it at all, unless it is in the same directory of the processed file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Frakturfreak! May be clear to every one, but any problems with writing permissions, just run with `sudo mktexlsr`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue using BasicTex 2015 and none of the above solved it, so I wrote up a [solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160253/latex-cannot-find-sty-files/#280684)

In short: `sudo tlmgr install preprint` will fix it and `kpsewhich fullpage.sty` will confirm the fix

Answer (score 0):

[This page on LaTeX packages](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/LaTeX/AoPS_L_GuidePack.php#own) says you'll need to install the `.sty` file in the LaTeX installation directory (my installation of Ubuntu seems to be `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/`), or you need to have a copy of the `.sty` file in *each* file containing LaTeX source -- i.e. in your `tex/documents` folder, at the very least.

Answer (score -6):

I tried this one it is works for me:

`sudo apt-get install texlive-full`.

Comment: On the whole this is not an answer for OSX, more likely for Ubuntu or some other Debian-based Linux distro.