# Permission denied for moving files on Terminal

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to move a file with Terminal into a folder I cannot see from the Finder. I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.5. The command I wish to use is `cp /mcq.sty /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex`. The result is `cp: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mcq.sty: Permission denied`. Is there a way to bypass that or to see that folder from the Finder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sudo` in front of your commands. See also [How do I install a LaTeX .sty file on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390828/how-do-i-install-a-latex-sty-file-on-osx)

In order to open a folder in Finder from terminal, type `open folderName`, e.g., to open the current folder, use

```
open .
```

or to open the folder mentioned, use

```
open /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/
```